# Vercel Deployment Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 1. When deploying Next.js web app

Tags: javascript, next.js, vercel

I am developing a Next.js app that work locally. But when I deploy im getting this error.

`Vercel Deployment Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 1`

This is my building log -

```
[08:26:17.892] Cloning github.com/Bossman556/TechMoneyLlc (Branch: main, Commit: 1fdf14b)
[08:26:17.899] The cli flag --force was set. Skipping build cache download.
[08:26:20.729] Cloning completed: 2.837s
[08:26:21.188] Not using Build Cache
[08:26:21.242] Running "vercel build"
[08:26:21.887] Vercel CLI 28.4.14
[08:26:22.295] Detected `package-lock.json` generated by npm 7+...
[08:26:22.306] Installing dependencies...
[08:26:40.266] npm WARN deprecated core-js@3.6.5: core-js@<3.23.3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Some versions have web compatibility issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.
[08:26:44.660] 
[08:26:44.661] added 518 packages in 22s
[08:26:44.661] 
[08:26:44.661] 95 packages are looking for funding
[08:26:44.661]   run `npm fund` for details
[08:26:44.687] Detected Next.js version: 12.3.1
[08:26:44.694] Running "npm run build"
[08:26:45.093] 
[08:26:45.094] > scam@0.1.0 build
[08:26:45.094] > next build
[08:26:45.094] 
[08:26:45.684] Attention: Next.js now collects completely anonymous telemetry regarding usage.
[08:26:45.685] This information is used to shape Next.js' roadmap and prioritize features.
[08:26:45.685] You can learn more, including how to opt-out if you'd not like to participate in this anonymous program, by visiting the following URL:
[08:26:45.685] https://nextjs.org/telemetry
[08:26:45.685] 
[08:26:45.831] info  - Linting and checking validity of types...
[08:26:46.346] error - ESLint: Failed to load config "next/babel" to extend from. Referenced from: /vercel/path0/.eslintrc.json
[08:26:49.527] info  - Creating an optimized production build...
[08:26:49.891] info  - Disabled SWC as replacement for Babel because of custom Babel configuration ".babelrc" https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/swc-disabled
[08:26:50.658] info  - Using external babel configuration from /vercel/path0/.babelrc
[08:27:08.485] info  - Compiled successfully
[08:27:08.486] info  - Collecting page data...
[08:27:12.880] 
[08:27:12.880] > Build optimization failed: found page without a React Component as default export in 
[08:27:12.880] pages/vidsForCourses/VideoPlayer
[08:27:12.881] 
[08:27:12.881] See https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/page-without-valid-component for more info.
[08:27:12.881] 
[08:27:12.942] Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 1
```

I have tried solutions like setting environment variable  CI to false

```
CI = false
```

As well I have tried

```
In the "Build & Development Settings", override the Build command and write CI='' npm run build.
```

I have dropped the node verson aswell but that did not work.

Comment: **found page without a React Component as default export in pages/vidsForCourses/VideoPlayer**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the logs, you are having a component which may only export but not export default. And please remove the components inside the Pages folder, create a Components folder outside the Pages folder and move your components inside the folder.

Inside pages/vidsForCourses/VideoPlayer

make sure you export default

```js
const VideoPlayer = () => {
 return <div>Your contents</div>
 }
 //your code might be
 //export VideoPlayer;

 //To fix, add "default" on your export
 export default VideoPlayer;
```

Answer (score 0):

when i have same error when deploying on vercel. i think the issues is that vercel is running on Node.js Version that is different from your own app
i solve it doing this
Open your Vercel dashboard and go to the project where you're seeing the error.

Click on the "Settings" tab and scroll down to the "Node.js Version.
then change it to version 16 and everything works for me